# Is this function differentiable at $\pi/2$?

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x)$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\tan(x/2 + \pi/4) - (\pi/4)/(1-2 x/\pi) & \text{if $x \ne \pi/2$,} \\
0 & \text{if $x = \pi/2$}.  
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Combining fractions and then using L'Hopital's rule (twice), it can be seen that this function is continuous at $\pi/2$.

Since the only discontinutites of this function are at multiples of $\pi/2$, can we conclude, without any further calculations, that the function is also differentiable at $\pi/2$?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\!\!$

Comment: I don't think so. Differentiability of a function at a point ensures its continuity at that point but the converse of this theorem is not always true.

Comment: What is $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}{h}$$?

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $$\begin{align}x = \pi/2 + 2h, f(\pi/2 + 2h) &= \tan (\pi/2 + h) - (\pi/4)\left(1 - \frac{2}{\pi}(\pi/2 + 2h) \right)\\
&= -\tan h + h  = -\frac 13 h^3+\cdots\end{align}$$ therefore $f$ is differentiable  at $x = \pi/2$ and its derivative is zero.